# Настройка p2p ip камеры linux

Tags: linux, p2p

Извините, если буду писать бред, но интересует следующий вопрос: есть ip камера (hikvision), которая подключается через p2p. то есть, просто вводим серийный номер - и видео с камеры обрабатывается. без проброса портов, без статичных ip. Можно ли такое сделать самому на linux? То есть, сложить сервер, который так же будет принимать серийный номер камеры и подключаться к ней

Comment: При чём тут p2p? На сколько я знаю - у производителей видеокамер есть свои облачные хранилки и обрабатывалки. То, что ты не заводишь статический ip и не пробрасываешь порты - не значит, что это УЖЕ не сделано на серверах через которые ты смотришь стрим со своей камеры.

Comment: на сколько я понимаю, технология p2p позволяет камере постоянно оповещать сервер о своем ip как минимум. вот у меня как раз и вопрос: как самому перехватывать это оповещение?

Comment: @donRumata, причём тут сервера, через которые кто-то что-то смотрит?  В обсуждаемом случае камера просто инициирует соединение сама с сервером вендора. Проброс портов (а точнее NAT, если требуется) сделан на стороне маршрутизатора пользователя.

Comment: @0andriy, STUN?

Comment: так дело в том, что я не пробрасываю, но оно подключается